# Non-whitespace characters in scanf format string

Tags: c, scanf

I have a question about process that the scanf function takes when it encounters a non-whitespace character in the format string. According to the book I'm reading:

> When a `scanf` function encounters a non-whitespace character in a format string, `scanf` compares it with the next input character. If the two characters match, `scanf` discards the input character and continues processing the format string. If the characters don't match, `scanf` puts the offending character back into the input, then aborts without further processing the format string or reading characters from the input.

I am a little confused. It says that `scanf` compares it with the next input character and if the two characters match, `scanf` discards the input character. Why do we say that it compares with the "next" input character?

Does this mean that if we have a format string like
`scanf("%d/%d", &x, &y)` and the input `2/4`, `scanf` compares with the four because it's the next input character from the `/`?

Comment: No, `%d` reads `2`, the next input character is `/` and that gets compared with the `/` from your format string. Then `%d` reads `4`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of describing `scanf` is that for non-whitespace characters, it follows along the input with what it expects to see in the format string. However, if it finds a different reader, it "unreads" that character and then stops scanning altogether.

For example, let's look at:

```c
int x, y;
int scanned = scanf("%dabc%d", &x, &y);
```

If we give it the input `10abc20`, then it operates in this order:

- It reaches `%d`, reads `10`, and stores it in `x`.
- One-by-one, it reads `abc` and follows along with the `abc` given in the format string.
- It reaches `%d`, reads `20`, and stores it in `y`.
- It reaches the end of the format string, returning the value `2` for scanning two values.
- Leaving the code, all characters from the input is consumed.

Giving the same program `10abz20` instead:

- It reaches `%d`, reads `10`, and stores it in `x`.
- It reads `ab` correctly but when it reaches `z`, unreads that character, and returns early with the value `1`, since it only scanned the first number.
- Leaving the code, `z20` is left unread and may be read later in the program.

So in your example `scanf("%d/%d", &x, &y)`, the input `10/20` will scan completely, but `10d20` will only scan `10` into x and leave `d20` unread. As an aside, `10/ 20` and  `10/20` scans completely, but `10 /20` does not.